# Special linear group, efficient square roots calculation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

If it is known that the set of matrices being worked with all have determinant one, is there a special non general way of calculating the square root of the matrix?

To be clear I am looking for a method that does not in general work but works for the special linear group (matrices of determinant one)  may speed up the calculation over a diagnoliztion approach.

Comment: It might be helpful for you to clarify what you mean by *the* square root. In general there can more than one.

Comment: i will accept any of them for a given matrix B such that A^2=B

Comment: If there was a special way of calculating the square root of matrices in the special linear group, then you could easily make use of it for *every* matrix: Just divide the matrix $A$ by $c=(\det(A))^{1/n}$ to get a matrix with determinant $1,$ then apply your special algorithm, and finally multiply your result with $\sqrt{c}.$ In other words, it is not easier to calculate the square root of a matrix in the special linear group than calculating the square root of any other matrix.

Comment: ... at least if we are only dealing with invertible matrices.